# Redirect contactform7 to a page even with additional settings skip_mail:on

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am trying to redirect different forms on my website to unique thank you pages.

I have used and amended the current code, however it does not seem to work. I am assuming its because in my contact form i have skip_mail: on - listed in additional settings. When i remove that, it works. So i assume its also to do with the DOMevent 'wpcf7mailsent'

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirect_cf7' );
 
function redirect_cf7() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
   if ( '4380' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Sends sumissions on form 947 to the first thank you page
    location = 'https://domain_here.com/create-processing/?type=video';
    } else if ( '4086' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { 
        location = 'https://domain_here.com/create-processing/?type=channel';
    } else { 
        
        location = 'https://domain_here.com/create-processing/?type=none';
    }
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Is there any other way to acheive the above, without having mail sending turned on. My forms submit posts to my website and dont require sending emails.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `wpcf7submit`?

wpcf7mailsent - is an action triggered when a form submission is successful and an email has been sent.

On the other hand, wpcf7submit is fired when an Ajax form submission has successfully completed, independent of other occurrences.

You can read more about it [here](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/).

Therefore, you should attempt this code:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'redirect_cf7' );
 
function redirect_cf7() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
   if ( '4380' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { // Sends sumissions on form 947 to the first thank you page
    location = 'https://domain_here.com/create-processing/?type=video';
    } else if ( '4086' == event.detail.contactFormId ) { 
        location = 'https://domain_here.com/create-processing/?type=channel';
    } else { 
        
        location = 'https://domain_here.com/create-processing/?type=none';
    }
}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```